# Symfony internationalization with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, internationalization, bundle

I'm developing an web application with symfony2. Symfony features a build in internationalization for all PHP related parts.

Is there a way to use those build in internationalization parts in javascript too? Through any kind of bundle? I know there was one for symfony 1.4 but it doesn't seems to be updated any more.

If there is no bundle for it, what's the best way to implement internationalization with javascript when working with an framework which already contains a build in internationalization concept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: the bundle has been renamed to BazingaJsTranslationBundle, link updated.

You should have a look at this bundle : [BazingaJsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle)

> A pretty nice way to expose your translated messages to your JavaScript.

Comment: Note that this bundle has been renamed to [BazingaJsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle).